# Package jwnl.data does not exist

Tags: java, netbeans, package

I use Netbeans, when I try to import the package :

```
import jwnl.data.*;
```

i get the following error:

```
package jwnl.data does not exist
```

How can i download it and import it in Netbeans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the jar files for the API from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jwordnet/)

Then right click your project in netbeans, in properties go to library and add external jar.

Comment: thanks for replying, in Libraries window i can see 4 tabs, Compile,Processor,Compile Tests,Run Tests, in which one of them shall i add the jar file?